# Turning a tuple inside a function into a global value

Tags: python, tuples, global

I am trying to turn the text of a text file into a tuple. I'm a Python beginner and assume this code will be not as straight forward as it could be and thats okay with me (for now). All I am trying to do is making the tuple numbers_bank a global value so I can access it outside the function.

Printing the tuple from inside the function works but it doesn't work outside the function.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
*(It is a requirement that the output is a tuple, otherwise I would have changed it to a list and just append the elements.)*

```
global numbers_bank

def read_numbers():

    file = open("numbers.txt")
    num = file.read().split(",")
    num_new = [s.replace("[", "") for s in num]
    numbers_bank = [a.replace("]", "") for a in num_new]
    tuple(numbers_bank)

read_numbers()
print(numbers_bank)
```

Comment: You don't need a global—you're doing it wrong and it wouldn't have accomplished anything by putting it there in the first place. Anyway, just change the last line of the function to `return tuple(numbers_bank)` and then call it like this: `numbers_bank = read_numbers()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the global keyword works: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword

in your case it would be:

```
numbers_bank = None

def read_numbers():
    global numbers_bank

    file = open("numbers.txt")
    num = file.read().split(",")
    num_new = [s.replace("[", "") for s in num]
    numbers_bank = [a.replace("]", "") for a in num_new]
    tuple(numbers_bank)  # Note: this doesn't do anything

read_numbers()
print(numbers_bank)
```

However, global variables should be [avoided](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad).
Instead you should make the function return numbers bank in the following way:

```
def read_numbers():
    file = open("numbers.txt")
    num = file.read().split(",")
    num_new = [s.replace("[", "") for s in num]
    numbers_bank = [a.replace("]", "") for a in num_new]
    return tuple(numbers_bank)  # Now the 'tuplified' version of numbers_bank will be used for something because it is returned by the function

numbers_bank = read_numbers()
print(numbers_bank)
```

Please also note that the 'tuple(numbers_bank)' line doesn't do anything because you haven't assigned it to any variable.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful and the kind of simple solution that I was looking for. It makes sense now with the global value. So by returning the tuple in the function I make it the output once I call the function?

Comment: Exactly!  In the previous example with the global variable you could also do something like this:  

global numbers_bank

untuplified_numbers_bank = [a.replace("]", "") for a in num_new]
numbers_bank = tuple(untuplified_numbers_bank)


But the second solution is preferable, you turn it into tuple by making the read_numbers() function return the output of the tuple() 'function'.
The tuple() function doesn't change the variable you put into it, it just returns a tuplified version of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for:

```
>>> def read_numbers(): 
...:     global numbers_bank 
...:     # do stuff 
...:     numbers_bank = [1, 2, 3] # create some list
...:     numbers_bank = tuple(numbers_bank)                                                                                                                   

>>> read_numbers()                                                                                                                              
>>> numbers_bank                                                                                                                               
(1, 2, 3)
```

What you should do instead:

```
>>> def read_numbers(): 
...:     # do stuff
...:     numbers_bank = [1, 2, 3] # create some list
...:     numbers_bank = tuple(numbers_bank) 
...:     return numbers_bank 

>>> numbers_bank = read_numbers()                                                                                                              
>>> numbers_bank                                                                                                                               
(1, 2, 3)
```

Changing global state within a function can become messy and hard to comprehend very quickly. It's cleaner to `return` the value you are computing from a function and then explicitly assign a name to that return value whenever possible.

Also note that it's a little more concise to use `tuple(generator-expression)` over using a list comprehension and then applying the `tuple` constructor to the result of the comprehension, i.e.

```
numbers_bank = tuple(a.replace("]", "") for a in num_new)
```